# AngularJS filter not working when filter's model is in different view which has same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I have two views with same controller "TabsController as TabsVM". I need to use filter in second view, "item in items | filter:modelName" and modelName is in first view in an input field. Its not working, It works when I put input field in the same view where I am using filter, How can I do it without having to merge these views?

## UPDATE:

well I tried a lot but not able to connect models in filter.

## first_view.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="NavigationBarController as NavBarVM">
        .......
        .......
    <input type="search" class="form-control" ng-model="NavBarVM.searchInputFieldText" ng-change="NavBarVM.updateSearchInputValue()"/>
        .......
        .......
</nav>
```

## first_view.js

```
app.controller('NavigationBarController', ['$scope', 'NewProjectService', function ($scope, NewProjectService) {

    var vm = this;

    NewProjectService.searchInputFieldText = vm.searchInputFieldText;

    vm.updateSearchInputValue = function()
    {
        NewProjectService.updateSearchInputFieldText(vm.searchInputFieldText);
        NewProjectService.searchInputFieldText = vm.searchInputFieldText;
    };
}]);
```

## second_view.html

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 testTabsArea" ng-controller="TabsController as TabsVM">
        .......
        .......
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="panel in TabsVM.panels | filter:TabsVM.searchInputFieldText">
        .......
        .......
</div>
```

## second_view.js

```
app.controller('TabsController', ['$scope', 'NewProjectService', function ($scope, NewProjectService)
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.searchInputFieldText = NewProjectService.searchInputFieldText;
    ............
    ...........
}]);
```

## service.js

```
app.service('NewProjectService', function(){
...........
...........
    var searchInputFieldText = '';
    var updateSearchInputFieldText = function(text)
    {
        searchInputFieldText = text;
    };
    return{
        updateSearchInputFieldText: updateSearchInputFieldText,
        searchInputFieldText: searchInputFieldText,
    };

});
```

Comment: because currently on each view `TabsController` has different instances, basically you should create an `service/factory` which will help you to share data amongest this controller.

Comment: please let me know if you can find the error in my updated code using service now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Controller is a factory function that is returning an object and in your scenario you're calling your controller twice which means that you'll have two different objects in your views.

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Update:

Try changing

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="panel in TabsVM.panels | filter:TabsVM.searchInputFieldText">
```

to

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="panel in TabsVM.panels | filter:NavBarVM.searchInputFieldText">
```

Comment: could you please look at  my updated code this time using service and tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: Is your second view nested in first view?

Comment: no, if it was nested I don't think this problem would have happened.

Comment: finally I merged the code and its working now, but I don't know why its so difficult to share models between views when they are in different files or not nested in one file.